# Connect the high value of all the candles with a specific condition

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

At the first I want to search for a candle that its high value is higher than previous and next candle. For example, suppose we have three candle's high value: `high[0]` , `high[1]` and `high[2]` .
The condition is `high[0]<high[1] And high[1]>high[2]` . Then all the candles's high with this condition connect to each other with plot command. My code is connected all the candles after the candle that has this condition.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script" , overlay = true)
plot(high<high[1] and high[1]>high[2] ? high[1] : na)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you find a new pivot, you should draw the line from the last pivot, and record the new pivot as the last pivot.
A working example :

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay = true)

var LastPivot = high
var LastPivotIndex = bar_index
if high < high[1] and high[1] > high[2]
    line.new(bar_index[1], high[1], LastPivotIndex, LastPivot, color=color.red, width=2)
    LastPivot := high[1]
    LastPivotIndex := bar_index[1]
```

Gives :
[image]